# bundler does not install gem in current rvm gemset if gem is from remote repository

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I have selected a gemset with

`rvm use ruby-2.1.2@deploy`

in my gemfile I have:

`gem 'transip', :git => 'git://github.com/rempargo/transip.git'`

then I run `bundle install` and get the following output:

```
....
....
Installing wasabi 3.3.0
Installing savon 2.5.1
Using transip 0.4.2 from git://github.com/rempargo/transip.git (at master)
Using bundler 1.6.2
Your bundle is updated!
```

But when I do `gem list` all gems except the `transip` one are listed.
The other gems are not installed in gemset 'ruby-2.1.2' or 'ruby-2.1.2@global', but are really installed in the gemset `ruby-2.1.2@deploy`

I tried also to use `bundle exec install` although I never used the 'exec' before, but it does not work.

- Is there a problem using bundler and rvm when using gems that uses a link to a repository?

I'm using:
Mac OS X 10.9.3 (With command-line tools installed)
rvm 1.25.26
bundler 1,6,2

P.S. This all happened after upgrading to Maverick, when some libraries where not working anymore, and I had to install ruby again with rvm.

Comment: Due to the fact `bundle install` says 'Using' instead of 'installing', I guess it is not installing it all in the gemset. How to force that?

Answer (score 0):

`gem list`  will show all the gems installed on your system

`bundle show gem_name`will give you whether that gem is installed in your current application bundled gemset

Comment: I'm using rvm, so `gem list` will give me all the gems in the current rvm gemset.